# Using procedural noise with the displacement modifier

Tags: modifiers, displacement, procedural

Applying the displace modifier changes to another random noise map. is there a way to "lock" the current generated noise?

Comment: This is an interesting bug, didn't reliaze before. Try to bake the noise as texture, then use it for the disp modifier.

Comment: To add to FFellers comment: This YT-Tutorial explains the process of backing the displacement map pretty well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McALCOr39rY&t=256s